# In-Sample Forecast DCC-GARCH in R

Tags: r, forecasting

I'm estimating a DCC-GARCH with VAR(1) in mean for daily financial data.

Also the out-of-sample forecasts starting from the last date as well as the rolling out-of-sample forecasts seem straightforward, I struggle to find a way to get in-sample forecasts more than 1 period ahead.

Namely, if my dataset has the form: [day 1, day 1000], I would like to fit the model on the entire dataset, and then to have the following forecast: starting from day 500, what does my model forecast for the volatility in day 505?

Sorry if the question looks trivial, but for the moment the only solution that I found only works for univariate GARCH: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/7932/forecasting-using-rugarch-package

Many thanks!

P.S.: My model would have the following form:

```
garchOrder   <- c(1,1)
garch11.spec <- ugarchspec( variance.model = list(garchOrder = garchOrder,
                model = "sGARCH"),
                distribution.model = "norm")

dcc.garch11.spec <- dccspec(uspec = multispec( replicate(5, 
                            garch11.spec) ),
                            VAR = TRUE, robust = TRUE, lag = 1,lag.max = 12,
                            dccOrder = c(1,1),
                            distribution = "mvnorm")        


dcc.fit = dccfit(dcc.garch11.spec, data = data_returns[,c(1,2,3,4,5)])
```

Comment: It seems to me that using the function `dccsim` could be useful for that. I thought that  `dccsim` was just performing a simulation over `n.sim` periods (that is, it was drawing future shocks and simulate a future "path" for my returns according to those shocks). Yet if we start the simulation from different starting points, and if `n.sim` is high enough, we finally get the same simulation at the end (which shouldn't be the case with a random simulation, but which is normal for a mean-reverting process forecast). So could I use dccsim for in-sample forecasts according to this result?